# Adding Oblique imagery basemap to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, basemap

Is it possible to include oblique imagery in ArcMap?

The default basemaps only offer orthographic view basemaps.

I need to add an oblique view and show my other layer shapefiles in this oblique view.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to [Garmin's BirdsEye Imagery product](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/digital/maps/birdseye-satellite-imagery-subscription/prod70144.html), or just overhead view imagery in general?

Comment: I should have said Oblique imagery instead of Birds Eye.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by birds eye view,  you mean like an aerial map?  If that's what you mean then of course you can add these to your maps and whatever layers you want to add on top of them as well.

I think these will help:

- [Bing Maps Use in ArcMap Has Changed](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/04/12/bing-maps-use-in-arcmap-has-changed/)
- [Bing Maps Aerial](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=25c3f49d4ce3451e8a7f5b5aebccab48)

The first link above has updated information about Bing Maps as well as other services you can use for aerials.

Comment: The links you shared allow only orthographic views and not oblique views